# Laravel date format in where condition

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have this code

```
use Carbon;
$now = Carbon::now()->toDateString();
```

So i get the date without the time

```
public funtion test($brandid){

     $nbofsale=DB::table('st_nsales')
                         ->where('brand_id', $brandid)
                         ->where('eodate', $now)
                         ->get();
     return $nbofsale; 
}
```

The `eodate` field in the select is datetime. I want to put it in this query as date only and not to change the field type in database.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `eodate` is a timestamp, you don't need to convert it to a date string:

```
$nbofsale = DB::table('st_nsales')
              ->where('brand_id', $brandid)
              ->whereDate('eodata', Carbon::today()->toDateString());
              ->get();
```

Another way to get record for today:

```
$nbofsale = DB::table('st_nsales')
              ->where('brand_id', $brandid)
              ->where('eodata', '>', Carbon::now()->startOfDay());
              ->get();
```

Comment: but Carbon::now(); returns the date with time, that's why I did the conversation. But my problem is that i want to convert the eodate field to date only without time, So  the query condition compares the 2 dates without the time

Comment: in mysql the eodate type is DATETIME

Comment: @ElioChamy try the updated code with and without `toDateString()`

Comment: missing argument 3 for whereDate()

Comment: @ElioChamy 3rd parameter is optional `public function whereDate($column, $operator, $value = null, $boolean = 'and')` Please check your code again for errors. I've also added another way to get the data for today.